# How can I turn a massive number of coordinates into a boundary or polygon?

Tags: python, google-maps, kml, coordinate-systems, simplekml

I've got a large number of points that, when plotted individually, make for huge KML files. I would like to create a boundary for these points rather than plotting them individually. I am using python and a package called simplekml.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having tomany points, you can put all those coordinates to form lines or polygons. For doing lines see the example from the simplekml [Linestring tutorial](http://simplekml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tut_linestring.html). You can also learn from the [MultiGeometry tutorial](http://simplekml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tut_multigeometry.html).
Depending on the resolution that you need, you can also try to decimate your data with python before passing it to kml.